# Android: Disable double tap on clickable textview

Tags: android, textview, tap

This is the xml for the textview

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:id="@+id/signInTV"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#EB7B59"
        android:textColor="#524656"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="signInButton"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

This is the code:

```
public void signInButton(View view) {
    TextView signInTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signInTV);
    signInTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent showSignInActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(showSignInActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

Why is it that i can still only double tap on the textview and not single tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in the click event handler, and you are receiving the clicked View as parameter so there's no need to find it again.
This should start the Activity.

```
public void signInButton(View view) {
    Intent showSignInActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(showSignInActivity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
   public void signInButton(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.signInTV){    
                Intent showSignInActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(showSignInActivity);
        }    
    }
```

You already have an OnClickListener specified in the XML code, you add another listener inside the first one. That's why you have to click two times.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the `OnClickListener` with the first tap. The second tap then uses the `OnClickListener` with the `intent`

Your code should only be like this:

```
public void signInButton(View view) {
    Intent showSignInActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(showSignInActivity);
}
```